# Method inheritance on contravariant type

Tags: scala, typeclass, contravariance

I have defined two typeclasses:

```scala
trait WeakOrder[-X] { self =>
  def cmp(x: X, y: X): Int
  def max[Y <: X](x: Y, y: Y): Y = if (cmp(x, y) >= 0) x else y
  def min[Y <: X](x: Y, y: Y): Y = if (cmp(x, y) <= 0) x else y
}

trait Lattice[X] { self =>
  def sup(x: X, y: X): X
  def inf(x: X, y: X): X
}
```

I would like to do the following:

```scala
trait TotalOrder[-X] extends Lattice[X] with WeakOrder[X] { self =>
  def sup(x: X, y: X): X = max(x, y)
  def inf(x: X, y: X): X = min(x, y)
}
```

But this is impossible because contravariant type `X` appears at a covariant position (the returning value of `sup` and `inf`).

However, semantically this is correct: `max` and `min` with the type signature `max[Y <: X](x: Y, y: Y): Y` encodes the fact that the returning value of `max` / `min` must be one of the two arguments.

I tried to do the following:

```scala
trait TotalOrder[-X] extends Lattice[X] with WeakOrder[X] { self =>
  def sup[Y <: X](x: Y, y: Y): Y = max(x, y)
  def inf[Y <: X](x: Y, y: Y): Y = min(x, y)
}
```

However, the method `def sup[Y <: X](x: Y, y: Y): Y` cannot inherit `def sup[X](x: X, y: X): X`. The compiler complains that the type signature does not match. But the former one (with the on-site variance annotation) imposes a stronger type restrictions than the latter signature. Why the former one cannot inherit the latter one? How can I bypass the contravariant type restrictions on `TotalOrder[-X]` (semantically, a total order is contravariant)?

Answer (score 0):

This is not semantically correct. It should be clear from the definition of covariant and contravariant, but I'll try to give an example:

Suppose we have hierarchy of entities:

```
class Shape(s:Float)
class Circle(r:Float) extends Shape(Math.PI.toFloat * r * r)
```

And let's assume that it's possible to create contravariant orders, as you tried:

```
trait CircleOrder extends TotalOrder[Circle] {
   // compare by r
}

trait ShapeOrder extends TotalOrder[Shape] {
  // compare by s
}
```

By definition of contravariants, as `Shape <: Circle`,
`CircleOrder <: ShapeOrder`
(CircleOrder is supertype of ShapeOrder)

Suppose we have client that takes CircleOrder as the argument
and uses it to compare circles:

```
def clientMethod(circleOrder:TotalOrder[Circle]) = {
  val maxCircle = circleOrder.max(???, ???) // expected to return Circle
  maxCircle.r // accessing field that is present only in circle
}
```

Then, by definition of inheritance, it should be possible to pass
ShapeOrder instead of CircleOrder (remember, ShapeOrder is subtype):

```
clientMethod(new ShapeOrder {/*...*/})
```

Obviously it will not work, as client still expects order to return Circles, not Shapes.

I think in your case the most reasonable approach will use regular generics.

### Update

This is how you can ensure type safety, but it's a bit ugly.

```
    trait WeakOrder[-X] {
      def cmp(x: X, y: X): Int
      def max[T](x: X with T, y: X with T): T =
        if (cmp(x, y) >= 0) x else y
      def min[T](x: X with T, y: X with T): T =
        if (cmp(x, y) <= 0) x else y
    }

    trait Lattice[X] {
      def sup[T](x: X with T, y: X with T): T
      def inf[T](x: X with T, y: X with T): T
    }

    trait TotalOrder[-X] extends Lattice[X] with WeakOrder[X] {
      def sup[T](x: X with T, y: X with T): T = max(x, y)
      def inf[T](x: X with T, y: X with T): T = min(x, y)
    }
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying, and that's what I tried to do by the signature `max[Y <: X](x: Y, y: Y): Y`. passing two circles to a `ShapeOrder`'s `max` function should return a `Circle` but not a `Shape` because Circle <: Shape; thus the result type of `max` should be `Circle`.

Comment: @TongfeiChen Making type a contravariant implies that you need to have possibility to do something like this: `val cOrd:CircleOrderByR = new ShapeOrderByS`. Are you sure that this is what you need?  I would argue that different orders should be unrelated.

Comment: A total order, by its mathematical definition, is an order which is antisymmetric, transitive and total. By totality we mean that every two elements can be compared. A total order relies on only one function `cmp` (with signature (X, X) => Int) to define, thus it is naturally contravariant. E.g., A total order on real numbers (Double) naturally implies a total order on integers (Int).

Comment: @TongfeiChen So you are saying, that having implementation of `TotalOrder[Circle]` we can use is to find max of two `Shapes`?

Comment: `Circle <: Shape`; thus `TotalOrder[Shape] <: TotalOrder[Circle]` (hence contravariance). This means that an order on shapes is an order on circles; i.e. an implementation of a TotalOrder[Shape] can be used to find the max of two Circles.

Comment: @TongfeiChen ok, I finally got your point. Please check the update to my answer.

Comment: Yeah this works. Thank you :-) But i found out an easier workaround: @scala.annotation.unchecked.uncheckVariance ...